# ASP.NET Core Identity Claim inheritance not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

According to the docs, when I add a user to a role, he inherits all of its claims. However, I have hit a roadblock where I know the user has a specific role and I also know that these roles have some claims, but neither `User.Claims` nor `UserManager.GetClaimsAsync()` returns these claims.

I have already tried to refresh the sign-in-cookie, but it did not seem to have any effect. Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is a known bug in ASP.NET Core 2.1 (see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1997)), so upgrading to v 2.2 fixed the issue for me.